# wrapping text from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program that will open a specified file then "wrap" all lines that are longer than a given line length and print the result on the screen.

```
def main():
    filename = input("Please enter the name of the file to be used: ")
    openFile = open(filename, 'r+')
    file = openFile.read()
    lLength = int(input("enter a number between 10 & 20: "))

    while (lLength < 10) or (lLength > 20) :
        print("Invalid input, please try again...")
        lLength = int(input("enter a number between 10 & 20: "))

    wr = textwrap.TextWrapper()
    wr.width = lLength
    wr.expand_tabs = True

    wraped = wr.wrap(file)

    print("Here is your output formated to a max of", lLength, "characters per line: ")
    print(wraped)
main()
```

When I do this instead of wrapping it prints everything in the file as a list with commas and brackets, instead of wrapping them.

Answer (score 2):

[`textwrap.TextWrapper.wrap`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.TextWrapper.wrap) "returns a list of output lines, without final newlines."

You could either join them together with a linebreak

```
print('\n'.join(wrapped))
```

or iterate through and print them one at a time

```
for line in wrapped:
    print(line)
```